# start cassandra on google cloud on debian vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have created a `Debian` VM and followed the steps to install cassandra on it. In the end, when I ran `sudo apt update`
`sudo apt install cassandra`

`cassandra` was installed and also automatically started.

However, `cassandra` wasn't added to `PATH`. I stopped cassandra using `ps -aux|grep cassandra` and `kill pid`. Now when I am trying to start it again using `cassandra -f`, I am getting several `permission denied` errors. eg

```
/usr/sbin/cassandra -f
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file /var/log/cassandra/gc.log due to Permission denied
```

I can try using `-R` option and start `Cassandra` as `root` but it is not recommended. How can I start `cassandra` as normal user?

Comment: Change the permissions for the `/var/log/cassandra` directory. Add the user that you are running Cassandra as to the group for this directory. Review the commands `whoami`, `chmod`, `chown` and `chgrp`.

Comment: thank you. Happy to accept your answer if you can provide it.